# WPML Permalink missing language slug

Tags: permalinks, plugin-wpml

I have a new WordPress and I added a page:

```
/fr/les-solutions
```

And I can see the permalink properly in the backend editor. However, when I click on the link, it redirects me to:

```
/les-solutions/
```

I've tried to re-save the permalinks and nothing has changed.
Anyone know why it's removing the language slug from the url?

### Update

My language URL format setting is set to **Different languages in directories** and I checked the **Use directory for default language.** and for the Root Page, I've chose the option **A Page**.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried "re-booting" your WordPres slugs? Just go to "Settings > Permalinks" and hit the "Save" button so WordPress re-generates it's permalink data...

Comment: @MacPrawn Yes I've tried it many times. The permalinks in the backend shows up properly though.

Comment: Hmmm - yes, they still would show ok on the back-end... Have you checked your .htaccess file? Any strange non-WordPress rules in there?

Comment: @MacPrawn Nope the .htaccess is the raw one of WordPress.